# Extract parts from Array keys in php and combine them

Tags: php, arrays

i have also got a similar question. I have an array where i need to extract parts from the keys of array and combine them. can you please suggest the best way for it.

```
$myarray=Array(
[0]=>'unwanted text'

[1]=>'unwanted+needed part1'

[2]=>'needed part2'

[3]=>'needed part3'

[4]=>'unwanted text'

)
```

how can i extract only the needed parts and combine them. Thanks a lot ahead.

Comment: How do you define 'unwanted' and 'needed'? What do you mean by 'combine them'?

Comment: Actually the needed text starts from 'www' , it's a link but the link is broken into part wise like 
    [0]=>''www'
    [1]=>'example'
    [2]=>'Fitems'
    [3]=>'Fdetails'

Comment: And what is _unwanted_ then? How do you decide that?

Comment: everything before link and after link,and even between there is letter 'F' which i have to remove

Comment: When/Where does the link end? Why is 'F' not part of the link? Can you please show the actual array you are working with? It's hard to guess from your made up example data.

Comment: Array ( [0] => return [1] => 'id' [2] => 'id [3] => ' [4] =>           'name' [5] => ' [6] => ' [7] => 'burl' [8] => 'www [9] => example [10] => com [11] => Fproduct [12] => Findex [13] => Fid [14] => F [15] => F [16] => Futm [17] => source [18] => google [19] => games [20] => utm [21] => medium [22] => Dcpc [23] => utm [24] => campaign [25] => google [26] => market [27] => utm [28] => content [29] => D [30] =>go [31] => tovar [32] => ' )

Comment: This is the real part of the array which i am extracting and now i need to get the link from here as a text and so that i can save the link in my database. text needed to extract is
www.example.com/product/index/id/

Comment: Why are all your slashes replaced by `F`? Where do you get this array from? I think tinkering with the array is not the best idea, if you can get hold of the original data instead.

Comment: well i don't know why my array is comming like that but i suppose that maybe it's due to some reasons that not everyone extracted their links and used it easily (may be). i can't get this link by any other way.  I need to use this array anyhow to extract links.

Comment: i want all keys starting from www till the end of the array. rest i can do myself(hope so). i want somthing that can compare the first part of the unwanted text by 'www' and remove that first part. Hope you are getting me right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this does what you want, but looping and copying to a new array should basically achieve your result (once you clarify how you decide which part of the strings are needed or unwanted)

```
$myarray = array(…);
$new_array = array();
$unwanted = 'some_string';
foreach($myarray as $k => $v) {
  $new_value = preg_replace("/^$unwanted/", '', $v); # replace unwanted parts with empty string (removes them);
  if(!empty($new_value)) { # did we just remove the entry completely? if so, don't append it to the new array
    $new_array[] = $v; # or $new_array[$k] if you want to keep indices.
  }
}
```

Assuming you want to join array entries and have a string as result, use the [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) function of PHP: `$string = implode(' ', $new_array);`

Comment: This version is very good but i have one more question here. The text what i want starts from 'www' and has got in different key values for example in first case [9]=>'www' and in second case [7]=>'www'. So can i have somthing to compare and remove all text before 'www' till the end of the array.

Comment: [`array_search`](http://php.net/array_search) in combination with [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are after, depending on what you want to do, will be a combination of the following: `array_splice`, `array_flip`, `array_combine`.

**array_splice()**
allows you to extract part of an array by key offset. It'll permanently remove the elements from the source, and return these elements in a new array

**array_flip()**
Turns keys into values and values into keys. If you have multiple identical values, the last one has precedence.

**array_combine()** takes two parameters: an array of keys, and an array of values, and returns an associative array.

You'll need to provide more info as to what you want to do, though, for my answer to be more specific.